# Are the addresses of single linked list are always in order

Tags: c++, linked-list

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node * next ;
};
int main()
{

    struct node *start;
    start = new node;
    start->num=-3267;
    start->next=0;
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter nums"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    struct node * trav =start;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        int a;
        trav->next=new node;
        trav=trav->next;
        cin>>a;
        trav->num=a;
        trav->next=0;
    }
    trav=start;
    struct node * temp=new node;
    trav=start->next;
    cout<<"+++++++++++++++++Simple print ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        cout<<trav<<"   "<<trav->num<<endl;
        trav=trav->next;
    }
    trav = start->next;
    cout<<"++++++++++++++++++++++order used print+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<(trav+2*i)<<"  "<<(trav+2*i)->num<<endl;
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
Enter nums
5

1
2

3

4

5

+++++++++++++++++Simple print ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

0x2c29c8   1

0x2c29d8   2

0x2c29e8   3

0x2c29f8   4

0x2c2a08   5


++++++++++++++++++++++order used print++++++++++++++++++++++++


0x2c29c8  1

0x2c29d8  2

0x2c29e8  3

0x2c29f8  4

0x2c2a08  5
```

Comment: Why all the down-votes?  This may be a naive question, but I don't think it's a bad one.  Unlike so many questions here, the OP actually gave code that's complete, concise, and readable, along with input and output.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The fact that they're currently in order is due to the specific allocator that you're using and can't be counted on to hold in general.  If you allocated other objects in between allocating list nodes, your list addresses would probably look different.

As a simple counter-example to why list nodes can't be guaranteed to be in order in memory, consider what would happen if you swapped nodes 2 and 3.  This is a completely legitimate operation to perform on a linked list, but since you're not reallocating the nodes, their addresses don't change.  So the addresses are no longer in order.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens to be that way in this case because you are not allocating anything else on the heap (with new). Your nodes can end up anywhere really.

Answer (score 0):

No. Generally speaking if you allocate and fill your records in one operation, then the memory will be allocated sequentially. But there is **NO** requirement that the address are sequential. Say you allocate 50 nodes in a linked list, then later allocate 10 more. Your first 50 will likely be sequential, but if you add nodes later, you may allocate from a completely different area of memory.